# Current transformer variable burden resistor for wider current range

Tags: current-transformer, power-meter

I want to use a current transformer to measure a 100A AC supply (240V domestic incoming supply) with a minimum current of 1mA, with essentially an Arduino. That seems quite a tricky brief so my instinct is to scale the voltage I am measuring from the CT in steps controlled by the Arduino.

So there would perhaps be 5 'relay+resistor' combinations which could be switched in parallel (controlled by the arduino) with the burden resistor to reduce the burden resistance, when they are all open circuit (so just the default base burden resistor in circuit), the CT output voltage would be suitable for measuring 1mA (so perhaps 0.5V max OP, biased to 0.5V to eliminate the need to rectify etc, fed into the 328Ps ADC), and by switching in a smaller burden resistor, the ability to measure higher currents would be added.

I know this would not allow me to measure 100A with a resolution of 1mA but I don't need to do that.

Obviously then the software would switch in smaller burden resistors if the ADC was indicating FSD, and remove burden resistance if the ADC was returning a very small value to increase resolution. Because it knows what resistance it has switched in it can calculate the correct result from its ADC reading.

I would also need to protect the ADC input from over voltage damage.

But I can't find anyone talking about scaling resistors with CTs on the web so I am wondering if there is some fundamental no-no there. From what I can see theres no problem with making the burden resistor smaller than the calculated best value and the only issue is getting a big enough voltage for your ADC, so you don't want to make the resistor too small. But making it smaller for 'over current' situations? I can't see any references to that.

Comment: Maybe you should link a CT that you might be thinking is suitable.

Comment: Re a suitable CT - I imagined they were interchangeable to some degree, ultimately I would prefer to use a non-split one but for initial work perhaps this one http://statics3.seeedstudio.com/assets/file/bazaar/product/101990029-SCT-013-000-Datasheet.pdf which is rated at 10 ohm max. Is that 10 ohms at 100A and at a lower current it will still not saturate with a higher resistance?

Comment: It may not saturate at a lower current with a higher burden resistance but, you will eat away at the accuracy of the output signal and, unfortunately, there are no clues in the data sheet that might indicate just how much this error could be.

Comment: @Andyaka could it be calibrated away?

Comment: Why would it do that? What's the underlying process?

Comment: Pete, here's a test to try, since as Andy has pointed out, the data sheet is lacking...do this test cautiously, because things may easily overheat. Connect the largest-value burden resistor that you intend to use, and pass current through the transformer - maximum rated current of 100A. Consider that your Arduino, or relays, or the supply that powers them may fail, resulting in the case described above.